# how to do check name $_POST if empty

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

how i can to do check name filed
example if he is empty i need to print failure.
i did try this to action_ajax_form.php

```
if (empty($_POST["name"]))
  {
    echo "error";
  }
```

but i have error. i understand how to check if empty but i don't understand how to check in POST
my code

ajax.js

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(
        function(){
            sendAjaxForm('result_form', 'ajax_form', 'action_ajax_form.php');
            return false; 
        }
    );
});

function sendAjaxForm(result_form, ajax_form, url) {
    $.ajax({
        url:     url, (action_ajax_form.php)
        type:     "POST", 
        dataType: "html", 
        data: $("#"+ajax_form).serialize(),  
        success: function(response) { 
            result = $.parseJSON(response);
            $('#result_form').html('name: '+result.name+'<br>tel: '+result.phonenumber);
        },
        error: function(response) { 
            $('#result_form').html('error. fail send');
        }
    });
}
```

action_ajax_form.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["phonenumber"]) ) { 

    $result = array(
        'name' => $_POST["name"],
        'phonenumber' => $_POST["phonenumber"]
    ); 


    echo json_encode($result); 
}

?>
```

Comment: _"but i have error."_ - **what** error? Please go read [ask].

Comment: @Alexander Emelyanov just for records you need to accept solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`isset( ... )`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.isset.php) combined with [`empty( ... )`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.empty.php) :

```php
if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){
  //Your var is not empty
}else{
  //Your var is empty or doesn't exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use trim() to check if $_POST['name'] is empty:

```
if( trim($_POST["name"]) == "" ) {
    echo "Error: Name is empty!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isset()` function to identify whether the variable has been set or not and is not null. Follow this [Official tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
<?php
$var1 = 'STACK_OVERFLOW';
var_dump(isset($var1));
?>
```

If the value has been set it returns true otherwise it return false.

You can also pass multiple variable to check if they are set or not like this

```
isset(variable1, variable2......)
```